# How do I toubleshoot Intermitant failure with an AFCI breaker?

Tags: afci

Six months ago I remodeled my kitchen.  Even though nobody is using AFCI breakers or recepticles in my area, I decided to use AFCI/GFCI receptacles as opposed to GFCI's.  The particular circuit in question is a 20 amp circuit run on new 12/2. I've double checked connections at both ends.  They are good. The only thing on this circuit is the AFCI receptacle and 1 additional receptacle, running off the load side of the AFCI.  No issue's until about a week ago.  Then one morning, no power.  I unplugged everything and tried resetting the receptacle, but it tripped.  At that point, not being used to AFCI I forgot to check whether that was a GFCI or AFCI trip?  We had a mouse issue a week before and I assumed it may have chewed through some of the insulation.  This Saturday when I went to re-run the line, it was fine.  I tested it a few times to make sure it came back on.  I also put a pretty decent load on it to test.  No issues.  What could have caused this?  Is there something I could do to troubleshoot or prevent this in the future?

Comment: Was anything plugged into the circuit when it tripped?  Anything at all?

Comment: What is normally plugged into the outlet and any other outlet daisy chained off that one?   AFCI receptacles are a waste; with AFCIs the aim is to protect the wires in the walls, so to be meaningful the protection has to be at the breaker.

Comment: Normally, nothing is plugged into the AFCI,  the Receptacle on the right usually has a coffee maker plugged into it.  However I don't believe it failed while the coffee maker was running.  Also, the coffee maker as well as other appliances seem to work without issue on that circuit.

Comment: Is the fridge on this circuit?

Comment: No. All major appliances are on dedicated circuits. This circuit is only the AFCI and one other outlet on the load side.

Comment: Generally an intermittent issue like this points to moisture building up somewhere and allowing a small amount of current to flow to ground, then it dries up and the problem goes away. In the kitchen, it may have been that someone was cooking or boiling something and made a lot of steam, which condensed around the unused and thereby cold receptacle. If it happens again, remember to check if it was a GFCI or AFCI trip.

Comment: What make and model is the AFCI/GFCI combo device in question?